# how Downgrade LG optimus P500 from 2.3.3 to 2.2.2

Tags: downgrade

I upgraded my LG optimus P500 phone from Android 2.2.2 to 2.3.3.
After upgrading the battery started to dry very soon and it auto powers off as well even when the battery is more than 80%.

Now I want downgrade my cell back to original froyo 2.2 version.

How can i do this?
Or is there any other fix for this problem of battery and auto power off.

Comment: You might try to wipe/factory reset and see if this solves it already.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem on 2.2 when I first bought it. Changing SD cards did not help. Resolved by uninstalling some apps. I believe it's a task killer or a launcher that's causing the SD card rebooting few times daily. Try deleting these apps one by one and monitor.